# C# em GraphQL: incluir diretamente um objeto em Type e também InputType

Tags: c#, graphql

Tenho uma classe de usuários:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
}
```

Para usar o objeto acima no GraphQL, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
public class UsuarioType : ObjectGraphType<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioType()
    {
        Field(f => f.id).Description("ID do Usuário");
        Field(f => f.nome).Description("Nome do Usuário");
    }
}
```

O mesmo para InputType:

```
public class UsuarioInputType : InputObjectGraphType<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioInputType()
    {
        Field(f => f.id).Description("ID do Usuário");
        Field(f => f.nome).Description("Nome do Usuário");
    }
}
```

> **Dúvida**: com objetivo de facilitar a manutenção evitando repetir os campos (`id` e `nome`), não é possível **converter diretamente** um Objeto em ObjectGraphType e/ou em InputObjectGraphType?

Comment: São implementações diferentes com `interfaces` distintas então até o momento não vejo como fazer isso. Vai depender também qual código esteja usando tem como dizer qual site está usando tem alguns para fazer GraphQL em C#. O GraphQL dotnet não dá, como relatado implementa interfaces diferentes ...